# inApp ServiceConnection doesn't respond

Tags: android

I am struggling with the ServiceConnection for inapt purchases. Neither methods on ServiceConnected or onServiceDisconnected get called.
Logcat is empty!
What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.inapp); 

    mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
            showtouser("Disconnection from server");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
                IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);

            bindService(new 
                    Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                    mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            showtouser("");

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofc it does nothing, because callback method onServiceConnected() is called after successful bind. Now you are calling bindService() after it has been bounded. This code has no action. Call it e.g. after setContentView(). Check docs http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html